# loop through a multi-dimensional array and echo the value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi-dimensional array that takes the form:

```
    array = [value1, some number],[value2, some number]...
```

I need to loop through the array and echo the value followed by a tokenizer so the final output looks like:

```
    value1!@#$value2!@#$
```

I know that I have to concatenate the return value with ."!@#$" but I do not know how to loop through the array. Can anyone offer some help.

My array is being made from a MySQL Query as follows:

```
    while($row = $results -> fetch_assoc()) {

    $return_array[] = array(
                      $row['uid'],($row['column1] - $row['column2']));
    }
```

Then I am perfoming a usort on the array

Comment: What PHP Version are you using?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your array? Something like `$array = [['value1', 1], ['value2', 2]];`? Have you tried using foreach?

Comment: Please show us your code. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be simple enough, you can use [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) and [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column):

```
$array = [['value1', 123], ['value2', 234]];
echo implode('!@#$', array_column($array, 0)) . '!@#$';
```

This gives:

```
value1!@#$value2!@#$
```

---

**Explanation:**

`implode` - Joins array values using some specified value, here `!@#$`

`array_column` - implode accepts one dimensional array, also you want only the first index of the array to be joined, so creating an array with just first index.